# Sending JavaScript code from c# windows application to a running instance of IE does not work?

Tags: c#, javascript

I'm working on a project in which I need to send a JavaScript function from c# windows application to a running instance of internet explorer and then the IE run the script and return the result to my c# application. (Very confusing? =) )

Just to make it more clear, here is the case:

I get the `IHTMLDocument2` of the running instance of internet explorer like this:

```
 htmlDocument = ObjectFromLresult(lResult,typeof(IHTMLDocument).GUID, IntPtr.Zero) as IHTMLDocument2;
```

Then I want to send a JavaScript function to the IE instance, the code can be something like this:

```
string code = "function myTest() { alert('ready'); } myTest();";
```

I use the following code to send the JavaScript code:

```
htmlDocument.Script.GetType().InvokeMember("eval", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, htmlDocument.Script, new object[] { code });
```

**now here is the question:**

Sending the above simple JavaScript code to IE works fine, but if I want to send codes that work with events (like `onmouseover`, `onmouseclick` ,etc), it  does not work and results in the following exception:

*TargetInvocationException was unhandled.
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.*

Q: how I can send JavaScript codes that use events like :

```
document.body.onmouseover = function(mEvent){...};
```

**note:** It's not ASP.net or web application, It's desktop application.

I always appreciated the knowledge and great ideas of you. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried invoking the method like this?:

```
string code = "function myTest() { alert('ready'); } myTest();"; 

htmlDocument.GetType().GetMethod("eval").Invoke(htmlDocument, new object[] { code });
```

Comment: To be honest, I did not check your solution. I just read about `htmlDocument.onmouseover` and related methods, which I think they may satisfy my needs better (not sure). But I just have some problems about these events too!  ( a real nightmare :( )